# web3.eth.getCode executes weirdly

Tags: web3js

I am trying to get a contract code from javascript. However, when I run this:

```
web3.eth.getCode("0x9bA082240DBa3F9ef90038b9357649Fa569fd763")
```

on my browser console, I get an Invalid address error which is unexpected. The above address is a valid contract address and the same function on my geth console returns the correct code. My geth client always syncs up with the blockchain. So my question: why is this problem happening? and how to fix it?

Comment: what is your eth --version ? on mine (1.2.0) is returns a too long stuff to paste in the comment :)

Comment: I check with other contract addresses, the problem still shows up. Seems like getCode only works with ...normal address (like personal address). But getCode is just to fetch the code of a contract?..

Comment: @euri10 mine is 1.2.1

Comment: Have you tried lower-casing all of the letters? The Case-checksum was only added recently and web3 may not be compatible with it yet

Comment: i am also facing the some problem, i deployed the contract using truffle/pudding and getting the address as well but when i do > web3.eth.getCode("0x48007968c0bd1cac4aef962754eab8c2d806b4aa") in geth it will give `"0x"`, what does it mean?. when i use `metaCoin` deploy ,the address is giving the code, but `tokenRecipient` contract is not working for me .. please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figure out why. IDK whether its a bug in the implementation, but the function **isAddress(address)** in web3.js is implemented like this

```
var isAddress = function (address) {
    return /^(0x)?[0-9a-f]{40}$/.test(address);
};
```

similarly for other functions like **isStrictAddress(address)**. When I changed the regex rule to accept A-F characters as below

```
var isAddress = function (address) {
    return /^(0x)?[0-9a-fA-F]{40}$/.test(address);
};
```

then things work fine.

Answer (score 1):

on eth 1.2.0 it returns, maybe your eth version is too old

```
> web3.eth.getCode("0x9bA082240DBa3F9ef90038b9357649Fa569fd763")
'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'
```

Comment: Did you try it on javascript console? The web3.js module?

Comment: I tried inside eth, misread you were trying in a browser, sorry

Comment: Yeah, i also got the result inside eth/ geth, but it doesn't work with the web3.js currently